# JQuery Animate Down And Scroll If Needed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

but only find scrolling solutions.

What I'm trying to do is move a circle across the screen using animate (left or right), then of course up / down, which I can do.

The issue is when I want the browser to scroll with the circle up / down if needed, in a nice smooth manner.

This is some simple quick dirty code I wrote just to mess around

```
$('#circle').animate({'left': (start)+'px'},'slow').fadeIn('slow', function(){
        $(this).animate({'left': '+='+(stopRight)+'px'}, 2000, function(){
            $(this).animate({'top': '+='+(downRight)+'px'}, 2000, function(){
                $(this).animate({'left': '-='+(leftRight)+'px'}, 2000, function(){
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Where / how would i make it scroll, Any suggestions tip, I plan on getting ride of the code I have below anyways.

Comment: So when the browser starts scrolling you want it to animate the circle along side the browser movement. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: perhaps you can get inspiration havign a look at the jquery scrollintoview plugin. It smoothly scrolls the page to show the focused control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working solution, based on your animation sequence:

**See this** [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/ytDPf/) Example!

**HTML**

```
<div id="circle"></div>
```

**CSS** <sup>normalized on the Fiddle, but not relevant</sup>

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #444;
  border: 1px solid #212121;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
}
```

**jQuery** <sup>You will need the plug-in `.watch()`, see link below</sup>

```
// initial values to your variables
var start     = 0,
    stopRight = 1000,
    downRight = 300,
    leftRight = 300;

// your code as it was
$('#circle').animate({'left': (start)+'px'},'slow').fadeIn('slow', function(){
  $(this).animate({'left': '+='+(stopRight)+'px'}, 2000, function(){
    $(this).animate({'top': '+='+(downRight)+'px'}, 2000, function(){
      $(this).animate({'left': '-='+(leftRight)+'px'}, 2000, function(){});
    });
  });
});

// the code to make it all happen!
$('#circle').watch("left,top", function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop  : $('#circle').offset().top,
        scrollLeft : $('#circle').offset().left,
    }, 20);
}, 100);
```

**Plug-in used**

[jQuery CSS Property Monitoring Plug-in](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Sep/12/jQuery-CSS-Property-Monitoring-Plugin-updated)

---

What this does is to track the element movement and manipulate the scrollbars to keep it visible at all times.

The jQuery [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) <sup>Get the current vertical position of the scroll bar for the first element in the set of matched elements.</sup>

The jQuery [.scrollLeft()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) <sup>Get the current horizontal position of the scroll bar for the first element in the set of matched elements.</sup>

The jQuery [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) <sup>Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.</sup>